# How to configure EM inside database without access to the web interface or SSH?

Tags: oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

I need to complete some tasks in EM. But I don't have access to the web interface or to SSH. Is there another way to configure EM? I think EM should have PL/SQL API, but I didn't find any information about it.

Only idea that came to my head is to implement a Java stored procedure that interacts with the CLI. But maybe less complex solution exists?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't really used it in any occasion, but this is probably what you are looking for ?

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B16240_01/doc/em.102/b40004/toc.htm

Oracle® Enterprise Manager Command Line Interface
10g Release 5 (10.2.0.5)

Comment: Thanks, but I know about it and even wrote about it in my question. CLI = Command Line Interface